# Maven not running tests through eclipse in multimodule project

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple multimodule maven project structure as below :

```
main-project : 
   -test-child-one : 
   -test-child-three : 
   -test-child-two :
```

When I run `mvn test` through eclipse from inside parent project, no tests are run.

I have also tried running `mvn test` from inside one of child projects - `test-child-one` , but tests are not run .

It always shows -

```
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The pom for parent and child are below :

**parent pom :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.atul.multimodule</groupId>
  <artifactId>main-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>main-project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>test-child-one</module>
    <module>test-child-two</module>
    <module>test-child-three</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**child pom :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.atul.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>main-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.atul.multimodule</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-child-one</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test-child-one</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

</project>
```

Is there anything I am missing here ?

Please help.

Comment: Following the convention to put the tests into `src/test/java` and named them like `*Test.java`? Have you tried to run in plain command line from the root location just by `mvn clean test`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't run from command line either

Comment: Can you make that project available via github or so? Otherwise it's hard to see where the issue is?

Comment: The name of test class was AppTestChildOne1.java and hence it was not getting picked by maven. Changing class name to AppTest.java works great

Comment: Of course it will not being picked up cause it does not follow the [naming schema](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). So you should name it like `*Test.java` etc.

Comment: You should post the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention over convention paradigm is important related to Maven that means you have a default directory layout and of course naming schemas.
This means you have to name your tests accordingly to those [schemas](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes).

To define unit tests you should name them like this:

- **/Test*.java
- **/*Test.java
- **/*Tests.java
- **/*TestCase.java